# gpg-agent instead of ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, gpg, gpg-agent

I have a Yubikey 4 and I want to use my GPG keys stored on this to authenticate to SSH servers.
I want to use GitHub for a start. I have already added my GPG authentication key to GitHub.

My problem is that when I ssh, my agent doesn't use this key. I've checked by trying to connect to my VPS with `ssh -v` but it skips my GPG key. My Yubikey is plugged in and `gpg2 --card-status` shows all the details. I am able to sign and decrypt fine as well as use the other features of the Yubikey.

The ssh ouput

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have disabled gnome password manager.

I've looked at [Connecting SSH and Git to gpg-agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174763/connecting-ssh-and-git-to-gpg-agent) and followed the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
╰─ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

╰─ ps aux | grep gpg-agent
wilhelm  26079  0.0  0.0  20268   980 ?        Ss   20:57   0:00 gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --sh
wilhelm  31559  0.0  0.0  12724  2184 pts/1    S+   22:49   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn gpg-agent
```

Comment: what is the command you are trying to connect?

Comment: `ssh -v wilhelm.co.za`

Comment: Do you have connection to your agent available? What does `ssh-add -l` outputs?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to add that to the question. Turns out I didn't. Editing now

Comment: when `ssh` can't open connection to your `gpg-agen`t, it can't use it. It is obvious. You need to add `--enable-ssh-support` to your gpg-agent as described in the linked question. You need to have at least `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, which should be generated by your agent. Common is to start the agent as `eval $(gpg-agent --options)`.

Comment: I had it this way. editing question to include

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ssh` can't open connection to your `gpg-agent` if you will not give it the way to do so.

When you start your `gpg-agent` with `--enable-ssh-support` option, it prints out environmental variables that needs to be available in the shell where from you will be using your `ssh`. There are few possibilities how to get them:

- Stop your `gpg-agent` and start it once more in like this in the shell where from you are using your `ssh` (this should be the easiest way to test it):

  ```
  eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --sh)
  ```
- Find the location of authentication socket and set up the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` by hand

Later on, when you will know that it works, you should set up the agent start according to the manual page for [`gpg-agent(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent), so probably in `~/.xsession` to let it start automatically.

Comment: Thanks man, It works perfectly :). Followed so many tutorials but none of them suggested this explicitly.

Comment: I'm just going to try restart and then I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: It worked fine with just the first bullet. After restart, it doesn't work(added to .xsession. So I just added the commands from the first bullet to my rc

Comment: And is `gpg-agent` running? What exactly does not work? We went through quite many steps of troubleshooting, you can do now on your own.

Comment: `pkill -9 gpg-agent
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --sh)` in my rc makes ssh work

Comment: so you might have the `gpg-agent` starting already somewhere else or `gnome-keyring` or `seahorse` can behave in the way of `ssh-agents`, but I have no idea where they start from. But great to hear it works for you.

Comment: Perhaps. At least it works now xD. When it breaks I can start over with a source-based distro and get all the other stuff out of the way